# Function returns NaN when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, function, object, web, nan

why myTodos.meetDone() functions return Nan?
it js of course and i just define an object called myTodos, and simply i wanna print console.log() the result.

```js
let myTodos = {
    day: 'Monday',
    meetings: 0,
    meetDone: 0,


    addMeeting: function (num) {
        this.meetings = this.meetings + num;
    },
    meetDone: function (num) {
        this.meetDone = this.meetDone - num;
    },
    resetDay: function () {
        this.meetings = 0;
        this.meetDone = 0;
    },
    report: function () {
        let meetleft = this.meetings + this.meetDone;
        return `Yo have ${meetleft} meeting for today!`;
    },
}

myTodos.addMeeting(2);
myTodos.addMeeting(5);
myTodos.meetDone(23);

console.log(myTodos);

console.log(myTodos.report());
```

any way first console.log is for debugging
why it's returning Nan i don't understand this!!!!

Comment: `meetDone` is a function as a well as a value

Comment: Rename the function `meetDone` to what it does instead so it doesn't clash with the property.  `removeFromMeetDone` or similar.

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing it this way rather than using a `class`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @AndrewBone already mentioned in his comment, your object has two properties called `meetDone`. The latter one overwrites the first, so when you add `this.meetings + this.meetDone` you are adding a function to a Number which results in NaN being displayed. Change the name of one of the properties, `meetingDone`  is even more descriptive than `meetDone` IMO

```js
let myTodos = {
    day: 'Monday',
    meetings: 0,
    meetDone: 0,


    addMeeting: function (num) {
        this.meetings = this.meetings + num;
    },
    meetingDone: function (num) {
        this.meetDone = this.meetDone - num;
    },
    resetDay: function () {
        this.meetings = 0;
        this.meetDone = 0;
    },
    report: function () {
        let meetleft = this.meetings + this.meetDone;
        return `Yo have ${meetleft} meeting for today!`;
    },
}

myTodos.addMeeting(2);
myTodos.addMeeting(5);
myTodos.meetingDone(23);

console.log(myTodos);

console.log(myTodos.report());
```

Comment: Or any other name you like, for example "addDoneMeeting" because that's what you are doing